# Convert special characters to normal characters

Tags: php, special-characters

`?` and `=` will be used as parts in my url. In generating the url, I use

`<?php echo l('node/'. $someID .'/delete?destination=chapter/'. $anotherID);?>`. When I check on `Firebug`, the `href` attribute of the link is not the usual url, instead of having `?`, it is being replaced with `%3F` and `=` is being replaced with `%3D`. How do I fix this?

Comment: [Url encoding](http://php.net/url_encode) - and don't trust firebug. View the source.

Comment: have a look at `http_build_query() `(http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) It will help you avoid these issues.

Comment: @MikeB Perhaps, but if `l()` actually performs URL encoding at some point, then he has his answer.

Comment: Is this the l() function in Drupal?

Comment: @MikeBrant, yes it is a function in Drupal and I think it formats url link as HTML Anchor tag. But why does it generate those unusual characters if it formats already?

Comment: @danielrsmith yes it is a function in Drupal and I think it formats url link as HTML Anchor tag. But why does it generate those unusual characters if it formats already?

Comment: give a try to htmlentities() http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I used the following code and worked for me:

```
rawurldecode(rawurldecode(l('node/'. $someID .'/delete?destination=chapter/'. $anotherID,array('absolute' => TRUE))));
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score -1):

Read the documentation of the l() function in Drupal (I assume you are using Drupal)

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/6

The 'html' option defaults to FALSE in the attributes array, however this needs to be TRUE if you are using HTML content...